CPC & CPM Calculator not updating all fields correctly when a change is made
I'm trying to replicate the following online calculator: https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/cpc-cpm.
The trouble is coding the Javascript so that whenever you manually update a field, the calculator updates the values in all other fields (except the one currently being changed) so that the calculations are always correct.
The calculations I refer to are as follows:

clicks = impressions * (CTR / 100)
total cost = (impressions * (CTR / 100)) * CPC
CPM = ((impressions * (CTR / 100)) * CPC) / impressions * 1000
CPM = (cost / impressions) * 1000
Impressions = (total cost * 1000) / CPM
CTR = (clicks / impressions) * 100
CPC = total cost / clicks
CPC = (CPM / 1000) / (CTR / 100) = 0.1 × CPM / CTR

Below is the JavaScript I have, but it's simply not working.
<script>
    const impressionsInput = document.getElementById('impressions');
    const cpcInput = document.getElementById('cpc');
    const ctrInput = document.getElementById('ctr');
    const clicksInput = document.getElementById('clicks');
    const totalCostInput = document.getElementById('totalCost');
    const cpmInput = document.getElementById('cpm');

    function calculateValues(changedField) {
        const impressions = parseFloat(impressionsInput.value) || 0;
        const cpc = parseFloat(cpcInput.value) || 0;
        const ctr = parseFloat(ctrInput.value) || 0;
        const clicks = parseFloat(clicksInput.value) || 0;
        const totalCost = parseFloat(totalCostInput.value) || 0;
        const cpm = parseFloat(cpmInput.value) || 0;

        if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'ctr') {
            if (impressions > 0 && ctr > 0) {
                clicksInput.value = (impressions * (ctr / 100)).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'clicks') {
            if (impressions > 0 && clicks > 0) {
                ctrInput.value = ((clicks / impressions) * 100).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'clicks' || changedField === 'cpc') {
            if (clicks > 0 && cpc > 0) {
                totalCostInput.value = (clicks * cpc).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'totalCost') {
            if (totalCost > 0 && impressions > 0) {
                cpmInput.value = ((totalCost / impressions) * 1000).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'totalCost' || changedField === 'cpm') {
            if (totalCost > 0 && cpm > 0) {
                impressionsInput.value = ((totalCost * 1000) / cpm).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'cpm') {
            if (cpm > 0 && impressions > 0) {
                totalCostInput.value = ((cpm / 1000) * impressions).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        if (changedField === 'ctr' || changedField === 'cpm') {
            if (cpm > 0 && ctr > 0) {
                cpcInput.value = (0.1 * cpm / ctr).toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }

    impressionsInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('impressions'));
    cpcInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('cpc'));
    ctrInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('ctr'));
    clicksInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('clicks'));
    totalCostInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('totalCost'));
    cpmInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('cpm'));
</script>

I'm fairly new to coding, but it just feels like rather than how it should be done (having the code be able to understand how the values relate to one another), I'm just having to specify "if this field and this field have values, this one can be worked out" etc..., which is never going to work?
Is there an efficient way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated even if its just helping point me towards the answer.
Thanks!
EDIT: Added runnable code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White background for the whole page */
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Consistent font */
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .form-container {
            border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 400px; /* Adjusted width */
            background-color: #f8f8f8; /* Light grey background */
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .form-group label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .form-group input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .form-group input:focus {
            border-color: #7c4dff;
            outline: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="impressions">Impressions</label>
            <input type="number" id="impressions" placeholder="Enter Impressions">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cpc">Cost per click (CPC)</label>
            <input type="number" id="cpc" placeholder="Enter CPC">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ctr">Click-through rate (CTR)</label>
            <input type="number" id="ctr" placeholder="Enter CTR">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clicks">Clicks</label>
            <input type="number" id="clicks" placeholder="Enter Clicks">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="totalCost">Total cost</label>
            <input type="number" id="totalCost" placeholder="Enter Total Cost">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cpm">Cost per mille (CPM)</label>
            <input type="number" id="cpm" placeholder="Enter CPM">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const impressionsInput = document.getElementById('impressions');
        const cpcInput = document.getElementById('cpc');
        const ctrInput = document.getElementById('ctr');
        const clicksInput = document.getElementById('clicks');
        const totalCostInput = document.getElementById('totalCost');
        const cpmInput = document.getElementById('cpm');

        function calculateValues(changedField) {
            const impressions = parseFloat(impressionsInput.value) || 0;
            const cpc = parseFloat(cpcInput.value) || 0;
            const ctr = parseFloat(ctrInput.value) || 0;
            const clicks = parseFloat(clicksInput.value) || 0;
            const totalCost = parseFloat(totalCostInput.value) || 0;
            const cpm = parseFloat(cpmInput.value) || 0;

            if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'ctr') {
                if (impressions > 0 && ctr > 0) {
                    clicksInput.value = (impressions * (ctr / 100)).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'clicks') {
                if (impressions > 0 && clicks > 0) {
                    ctrInput.value = ((clicks / impressions) * 100).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'clicks' || changedField === 'cpc') {
                if (clicks > 0 && cpc > 0) {
                    totalCostInput.value = (clicks * cpc).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'impressions' || changedField === 'totalCost') {
                if (totalCost > 0 && impressions > 0) {
                    cpmInput.value = ((totalCost / impressions) * 1000).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'totalCost' || changedField === 'cpm') {
                if (totalCost > 0 && cpm > 0) {
                    impressionsInput.value = ((totalCost * 1000) / cpm).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'cpm') {
                if (cpm > 0 && impressions > 0) {
                    totalCostInput.value = ((cpm / 1000) * impressions).toFixed(2);
                }
            }

            if (changedField === 'ctr' || changedField === 'cpm') {
                if (cpm > 0 && ctr > 0) {
                    cpcInput.value = (0.1 * cpm / ctr).toFixed(2);
                }
            }
        }

        impressionsInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('impressions'));
        cpcInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('cpc'));
        ctrInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('ctr'));
        clicksInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('clicks'));
        totalCostInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('totalCost'));
        cpmInput.addEventListener('input', () => calculateValues('cpm'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Please provide a minimal reproducible (ie runable) example with html and javascript. You can also use the <> button to create a runable code snippet

@derpirscher added, thanks!

Why are you checking the changedField, you can just do every calculation when something changed.

Hm, I see a bit of a problem in your formulas and the relations of the values between each other. Because for instance clicks, impressions and ctr build some sort of cycle.  Now imagine what happens if you manually change the value of impressions: You would need to update the value of clicks and ctr. But for calculating ctr you use the value of clicks and vice versa ... So when updating ctr you need also to update clicks, which leads to another update of ctr, which again leads to an update of clicks and so on and so forth. Not even sure, this cycle will always end
